# Unable to use ir receiver and motor shield together

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, arduino-motor-shield

```
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <AFMotor.h>
AF_DCMotor motor(1);


int RECV_PIN = 14;//The definition of the infrared receiver pin 11
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); //Open serial 
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Initialization infrared receiver
  motor.setSpeed(255);
  motor.run(RELEASE);
  Serial.println("start");
  motor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(1000);
} 

void loop() 
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    if(results.value==0x3D9AE3F7)
    {

      motor.run(FORWARD);
      delay(2000);    
    }
    else if(results.value==0x1BC0157B)
    {
      motor.run(RELEASE);
      motor.run(BACKWARD);    
    }
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);//Wrap output in hex receive code
    Serial.println();//For ease of viewing the output to add a blank line
    irrecv.resume(); //Receiving the next value
  }
}
```

Motor shield is not working when I use an IR receiver.
I tried connecting the ir receiver in different analog pins but it didn't work. I guess it's due to some error in my code but unable to figure out.

Comment: Is the motor using pin 1?

Comment: Yes I've connected the motor to pin1 also. I tried running the motor using a separate code and its working fine. @Delta_G

Comment: No by pin 1 I meant I connected the motor to the M1(motor ) pin of the motor shield. @Delta_G

Comment: What pin on the Uno is it connected to?   It says 1 in the constructor call.

Comment: I've tried connecting it (the ir sensor) in all the analong pins as they are not used by the shield @Delta_G

Comment: No the motor.  What arduino pin is the motor using?

Comment: It's an motor sheild so it's connected to all the pins and it sits on top of the arduino @Delta_G

Comment: But most of the pins come through.  Only some of them are used for the actual driving of the motor.  What pins does it use?   Oh never mind.  Just wait until someone who has one of those shields comes along and they may already know.

Comment: @Delta_G This shield runs 4 motors so it takes up a lot of pins. Only the analog pins and digital io 2 is free.

Comment: That seems unlikely but if true explains your problem.  If it is using pin 0 or 1 then you can’t use Serial.  What motor shield do you have exactly?   Do you have a link?

Comment: It's a normal adafruit motor shield https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield

Comment: Are you sure it's the V1 and not the V2?

Comment: This would be a lot easier to example if you specified (1) Exactly how are the motors connected to the Arduino -- how are the pins connected to the motor shield, exactly which motor shield are you using, etc. ? (2) Exactly what code are you using when the motors do work? (3) What do you expect to happen with the above code? (4) exactly what actually happens with the above code? (Is it a syntax error in the IDE? Does the IR reciever stuff seem to work, but not the motors? etc.)